# Proving that $E_{1} \cup E_{2}$ is measurable if $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are measurable

Tags: measure-theory

While proving that $E_{1} \cup E_{2}$ is measurable if $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are measurable, one step I encountered was

$m_{e}(T \cap E_{1}) + m_{e}(T \cap E_{2} \cap E_{1}^{c}) \geq  m_{e}(T \cap (E_{2} \cup E_{1}))$

where $m_{e}$ is the outer or exterior measure and $T$ is the test set.
How this step is correct.

Comment: $$T \cap (E_{2} \cup E_{1}) = (T \cap E_{1}) \cup (T \cap E_{2} \cap E_{1}^{c}).$$

Comment: @njguliyev. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand upon njguliyev's comment.

Note that

$$E_1\cup E_2 = E_1\cup(E_2\setminus E_1) = E_1 \cup (E_2\cap E_1^c)$$

so

\begin{align*}
T\cap(E_1\cup E_2) &= T\cap(E_1\cup(E_2\cap E_1^c))\\ 
&= (T\cap E_1)\cup(T\cap(E_2\cap E_1^c))\\
&= (T\cap E_1)\cup(T\cap E_2\cap E_1^c)
\end{align*}

and therefore

\begin{align*}
m_e(T\cap(E_1\cup E_2)) &= m_e((T\cap E_1)\cup(T\cap E_2\cap E_1^c))\\
&\leq m_e(T\cap E_1) + m_e(T\cap E_2\cap E_1^c).
\end{align*}